# Setting application host environment variable in Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, environment-variables

I have a Rails app that is hosted on heroku, being forwarded to from GoDaddy. My forwarding is working fine, but when you land on the app, the URL in the browser displays as my herokuapp URL, and I'm trying to change this.

GoDaddy is horrible with heroku and doesn't give you a good way to do this, but I read that you can set your `APPLICATION_HOST` env variable to your custom url. I'm just not exactly sure how to do this, or where this goes-- is it in the `production.rb` file in `config/environments`? I'm new to this and could really use some help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `config.action_controller.default_url_options = { host: ENV['APPLICATION_HOST'] }` to `config/environments/production.rb` inside the `Rails.application.configure do` block.

Comment: OK, thanks. Where would you set 'APPLICATION_HOST' equal to my custom url, though? or are you saying put the url in those square brackets?

Comment: That sets it to an environment variable so, as part of your deployment you could set an environment variable like: `export APPLICATION_HOST='app.example.com'` OR if you want to be a bit more static about it, then you could get rid of `ENV['APPLICATION_HOST']` and substitute it for the name `'app.example.com'`

Comment: OK-- thank you so much. I'll try this tonight after work! :)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to sign up for a free CloudFlare Web account and have them manage your DNS. You can edit your Nameserver settings on GoDaddy and replace with the urls given to you by CloudFlare. CloudFlare supports root CNAME flattening, so you can set up a proper yourdomain.com -> yourdomain.herokuapp.com and you'll never see the Heroku address.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#add-a-custom-root-domain